# How to insert images in horizonatal scrollview in custom adapter?

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

I am using custom `adapter` for `listview` where I put 4 sections.
Now i have photo section in which I put `HorizontalScrollView`. I got bunch of images from server so put them in string `array`.

```
    if (postDisplay.getImageUrl().equals("null")) {
            holder.photo_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
            holder.photo_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            String SharePhotos=postDisplay.getImageUrl();
            String temp=SharePhotos.replace("small", "big");
            String[] SharePicArray=temp.split("~");
            for (int i=0; i<SharePicArray.length; i++) {     
                ImageView imageview = new ImageView(activity); 
                imageview.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                imageLoader.DisplayImage(SharePicArray[i], imageview);
                String URL=SharePicArray[i];
                holder.image_layout.addView(imageview); 
            } 
        }
```

When I run this code first time it gives me right solution but when I scroll down and then scroll up to see again the images it again create another `imageview`.
If there is any other solution please let me know.
If there is any other `view` I can take to show images from server.

Comment: Hi! Please paste more code

Comment: I have implemented viewpager instead of horizontal scrollview. It works fine for me.